# replacement has length zero in nested loop

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a problem with a nested loop, here's the code:

```
T=2
dt=0.001
K=floor(T/dt)
t= seq(0,T,dt)

BM<- matrix(0,2000,1000)
for (i in 1:1000){
for (k in 1:K-1){
BM[k+1,i]=BM[k,i]+sqrt(dt)*rnorm(1)
}
}
```

the error message is:

```
Error in BM[k + 1, i] = BM[k, i] + sqrt(dt) * rnorm(1) : 
replacement has length zero
```

What is wrong in the loop?
The goal of it is to simulate 1000 sample paths of Brownian motion.

Comment: Your missing a ) in 1:(k-1). I think you could do this simulation without loops though.

Comment: @user3187955 you can [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if you consider your question has been answered, you can only accept one out them, but upvote more than one when you have enough reputation for upvoting ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a fully vectorized approach which gives the same result and it is faster than using `for` loops

```
B <-  mat.or.vec(K,1000)  # pre-allocate 
set.seed(1)
B[-1, ] <- matrix(rnorm((K-1)*100),K-1,1000) * sqrt(dt)
B <- apply(B, 2, cumsum)
```

Vectorized functions speed up your code as you can see in the benchmark results below:

```
          test elapsed relative
1 vectorized()   2.070    1.000
2   for.loop() 181.768   87.811
```

The vectorized approach is about 88 times faster than your two nested `for`-loops. Codes for the benchmark are shown below.

```
for.loop <- function(){  # this is your approach
  BM<- matrix(0,2000,1000)
  set.seed(1)
  for (i in 1:1000){
    for (k in 1:(K-1)){
      BM[k+1, i]=BM[k,i]+sqrt(dt)*rnorm(1)
    }
  }
  return(BM)
}


vectorized <- function(){  # this is my approach
  B <-  mat.or.vec(K,1000)  # pre-allocate
  set.seed(1)
  B[-1, ] <- matrix(rnorm((K-1)*100),K-1,1000) * sqrt(dt)
  B <- apply(B, 2, cumsum)
}


library("rbenchmark")
benchmark(vectorized(),
          for.loop(),
          replications=10,
          columns=c('test', 'elapsed', 'relative'),
          order = "relative")
```

Comparing the first 5 rows and 5 cols to check results:

```
> vectorized()[1:5, 1:5]
            [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]         [,5]
[1,]  0.00000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000
[2,] -0.01981021 -0.009865464 -0.008371525  0.015834886  0.001562361
[3,] -0.01400290 -0.037887974 -0.037253019  0.010349073 -0.024924006
[4,] -0.04042779 -0.098675011 -0.073133176  0.018483702 -0.066867547
[5,]  0.01001941 -0.047455576 -0.048955758 -0.001085329 -0.123356698
> for.loop()[1:5, 1:5]
            [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]         [,5]
[1,]  0.00000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000
[2,] -0.01981021 -0.009865464 -0.008371525  0.015834886  0.001562361
[3,] -0.01400290 -0.037887974 -0.037253019  0.010349073 -0.024924006
[4,] -0.04042779 -0.098675011 -0.073133176  0.018483702 -0.066867547
[5,]  0.01001941 -0.047455576 -0.048955758 -0.001085329 -0.123356698
```

Comment: hmm, never heard of `mat.or.vec`

Comment: since everyone is all about benchmarking here, `matrix(0,k,1000)` requires fewer keystrokes

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
for (k in 1:K-1){
```

Your precedence is off.  This will work:

```
for (k in 1:(K-1)){
```

Equivalently (for `K > 0`):

```
for (k in seq(K-1)){
```

Vectorization is better yet:

```
for (k in seq(K-1)) {
  BM[k+1,] <- BM[k,]+sqrt(dt)*rnorm(2000)
}
```